# Running python command line interpreter inside PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In matlab, it is possible to execute a script (ie an m-file) and then manipulate the variables created by the script on the command line.

Is it possible to run a .py file on PyDev and consequently, manipulate its variables inside eclipse as is possible in the case of matlab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, check the run configurations. You can add the script as a "Python Run".

Comment: Currently, the script is configured as a "Python Run". However, it only displays output on the console when run. My apologies I'm confused.

Comment: To debug it and view variables, you have to use the "Debug" command: Run -> Debug Configurations. Set some breakpoints in the code in question, and make sure the "Variables" view is visible.

Answer (score 4):

That's available through the PyDev interactive console. See: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html

Another way would be executing some program in debug mode and inspecting variables in the console: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_debug_console.html